# play sound on first time html page load

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to play audio on page load but i am getting error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var sound = new Audio("audio.mp3"); 
        sound.play();  

});
```

Comment: make sure the file path is correct

Comment: path is correct. first time its not playing when i click on anywhere in that page then it is playing

Comment: HTML `autoplay` or execution of `audioElement.play()` in JavaScript without user interaction is now blocked by most Browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this

HTML

```
<audio id="my_audio" src="bg.mp3" loop="loop"></audio>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeOut(function(){$("#my_audio").get(0).play();},1000)
});

var promise = document.querySelector('my_audio').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
$("#my_audio").get(0).play()
  });
}
```

please make sure that audio file is in same path.

Comment: I tried this one but its not working on first time got error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Comment: AutoPlay has been not supported by most of browsers : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample code. If you can use cookies it will be better

```
<audio id="my_audio" src="audio.mp3" loop="loop"></audio>
and add a script like this:

window.onload = function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
         document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
        localStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this works , I got error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException.

Comment: Try to implement same logic for promise exception <script>
  // Show loading animation.
  var playPromise = my_audio.play();

  if (playPromise !== undefined) {
    playPromise.then(_ => {
      // Automatic playback started!
      // Show playing UI.
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Auto-play was prevented
      // Show paused UI.
    });
  }
</script>

Comment: It's not working, I got error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Answer (score 0):

I found the way it works finally.

To enable sound on first time when page load run below link on google chrome

```
  chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy
```

then choose option "No user gesture is required".

and last click on "relaunch now" button for restart google chrome